# Moving an uploaded file onto a remote server

Tags: php, ftp

I am trying to move an uploaded file onto a remote server, this isn't working;

move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "uploads/$code1/$code.$fileex");

```
$ftp_server = "IP";
$ftp_user_name = "username";
$ftp_user_pass = "password";
$file = $tmp_name;
$remote_file = "/public_html/test/uploads/";

// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

// upload a file
if (ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file, $file, FTP_ASCII)) {
 echo "successfully uploaded $file\n";
} else {
 echo "There was a problem while uploading $file\n";
}

// close the connection
ftp_close($conn_id);
```

I get this erorr;

Warning: ftp_put() [function.ftp-put]: Can't open that file: Is a directory in /home/file/public_html/uploaded.php on line 52

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `$remote_file` variable is pointing to a directory when it should point to a file. Try changing $remote_file to `$remote_file = "/public_html/test/uploads/".$file;`

Comment: I'm trying to move a local file to a remote server.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. You need to specify the path on the remote server including the file name, however in your code you're not doing that. If you look at the docs for ftp_put (http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php) you'll see the second parameter is to the remote file, not the remote folder.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably wrap the portion that uploads the file in an if statement that checks to see if you are actually connected properly to the FTP

Also, when uploading a file, you need file 1 and file 2. Right  now you've supplied file 2 and a directory.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php

Answer (score 1):

The file you are trying to move to is the directory `"/public_html/test/uploads/"`, you need to append the filename and extension onto the directory.

Answer (score 0):

## Add the following line at the end of the /etc/vsftpd.conf file

Add ***pasv_promiscuous=YES*** it

Comment: it worked for me in ubuntu 14 using aws server in 64 bit