# Uploading via HTTP to different server

Tags: php, apache, hosting, storage

I'll try to be concise on this one:

I have 2 servers (well, don't have them yet, but it's not relevant), one of them is acting as web server with a feature of file upload (these are mostly few gigabytes PSD files) while the other is supposed to be storage server.

Currently I use a little app that checks continuously whether new files have been uploaded and send them over SFTP to storage server, that means I they're sent twice (uploaded to a server and re-sent to storage).

The question: is there any way to programatically upload the file directly to storage?

If the answer to above question is "no", would you point me to a solution allowing such upload?

**EDIT**

This question is not a duplicate of the given question, because I don't want to send the file to my web server and move it to storage by FTP, I would like the file to be uploaded directly to storage (not even temp upload to web server!)

Comment: Check out this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9622036/moving-an-uploaded-file-onto-a-remote-server

Comment: Thank you @Timothy, my question may seem unclear, but I know how to move my file via FTP once it gets uploaded to my web server, what I want to do is simply avoid this step and send the file directly to storage server (skipping upload to web server)

Comment: Try just pointing your form action to your remote server. Be sure your form method is a POST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I get you correctly you want people to use your web frontend server, but by klicking "upload" they should directly send the data to storage you don´t have to pay/wait/whatever for the traffic between the two servers.

Well, there is no way to upload a file to a server that is not accessible for the user. If it is, how ever, you can upload just the sam way you uploaded to the web server.

Extrapolating what the problem might be: Did you realise that you can use a full URL in the file uploads form action="..." tag, starting with http?

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. You're completely right, I can use full URL to send a form to storage server, but I wanted to keep it storage-only. Well, I guess that's the closest I can get to what I expected. Storage server is only accessible via FTP, but I'll have to re-consider my design then. Thank You very much!